# How to manually install the .jar file for tika?

Tags: python, apache-tika

I am using `tika` for extracting text from pdf in `python`. But, it downloads the .jar on every run. which is time consuming.

```
[MainThread  ] [INFO ]  Retrieving http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/tika/tika-server/1.19/tika-server-1.19.jar to /tmp/tika-server.jar.
```

This happens every time I run the code. Is there a way to manually do it once and stop `tika` to do it everytime?

Comment: Pop it wherever you want, and pass the `TIKA_SERVER_JAR` environment variable to specify it? See https://github.com/chrismattmann/tika-python#environment-variables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know it´s been a while and you probably figured something out already, but for others like me still looking for solution I would like to sugest other topic in wich the guy who asks the question presentes his own [functional aproach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56559850/python-how-to-use-tika-with-existing-jar-file-without-downloading-again).

Moreover, I noticed that tika demands internet access only at the very first run, so, if you manage to deny internet access for it after setting everything up, it won´t waste time downloading new files.

Comment: It is very useful to answer old questions. I encourage you to do so.